# Exponential Operators

Tags: operator-theory

What is wrong ? We have  the following identity 
[image]

I try to check  the equation, but I get a different answer
[image]

I have considered the simplest case, in theory I should get two commutators but ...
please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Hey, instead of providing links, can you include the maths in your post? You can use LaTeX (use dollar signs for encapsulation).

Comment: Hi, sorry, but I dont know how to use this code

Comment: @МаксТар [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial.

Comment: @HoseynHeydari Thank you ! very helpful.